# Postgres function not returning any rows but no errors

Tags: postgresql

I have this below function which returns no rows, but no errors as well. Am I missing any statement over here to return the rows?. If I execute the select statement alone I do get results.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.create_new_conversation()
 RETURNS TABLE(chat_id text, members jsonb)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare
   the_record record;
begin
   select conversation_id, participants
   into the_record
   from public.conversations
   where conversation_id='123456';
   
--    return conversationid;
end;
$function$
```

Comment: Why are you storing numbers as strings?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thats a text field, I just put in numbers for testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `return query` inside a PL/pgSQL function to return the result of a query (as a table). There is no need to store the row into an intermediate result:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.create_new_conversation()
 RETURNS TABLE(chat_id text, members jsonb)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
begin
   return query
     select conversation_id, participants
     from public.conversations
     where conversation_id='123456';
end;
$function$
```

But to wrap a SQL query into a function, no PL/pgSQL is needed. A plain SQL function will be more efficient:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.create_new_conversation()
 RETURNS TABLE(chat_id text, members jsonb)
 LANGUAGE sql
 STABLE
AS $function$
   select conversation_id, participants
   from public.conversations
   where conversation_id='123456';
$function$
```

As the function is defined as `returns table` you also have to make sure you use it like a table:

```
select *
from create_new_conversation();
```

Comment: Thanks a_horse_with_no_name for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `into the_record` portion of your code.